# How to set the range of an axis of time values in nvd3 options based on current min/max values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I got an old angular site that I need to build upon and one of the things I need to do is to change a chart using it's options object.

Right now the y axis goes from the lowest time to the highest time, but I need to create a bit of space above and below those, so that it will look better.

My thought was to add something like `range: [minVal*0.9,maxVal*1.1]` to the yAxis attribute, but that didn't work. I've been looking around and all the examples I found were of integers and floats, not of datetime.

Is there a way to get the lowest and highest values of an array of time and use that are put into the graph and how can I use those to alter the range of the axis?

Below is the current chart part of the options object.

```
chart: {
      type: 'lineChart',
      height: 600,
      width: 1200,
      x: function (d) {
        return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y').parse(d[0]);
      },
      y: function (d) {
        return d3.time.format('%M:%S.%L').parse(d[1]);
      },
      xAxis: {
        axisLabel: "Date",
        tickFormat: function (d) {
          return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d));
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        axisLabel: "Time",
        // range: [(minValue*0.9), (maxValue*1.1)],
        tickFormat: function (d) {
          return d3.time.format('%M:%S.%L')(new Date(d));
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.forceY([min, max])` on the chart declaration to force the Y-axis range:

```
var chart = ...;
chart.forceY([minValue * 0.9, maxValue * 1.1]);
```